# Paypal API: Getting list of orders

Tags: c#, paypal

So I am trying to get the list of the items that I have to deliver based off of orders between certain dates from paypal. I couldn't find any solution or explanation on paypal developer documentation on this.

So I use "paypal here" to receive POS payments for orders during the week. I wanted to essentially get an order list if you will (I was surprised that paypal didn't offer an api call for this). By order list I mean a list of customers and each customer's list of items(shopping cart) that they have ordered. I believe "paypal here" treats all orders as an invoice.

So after a lot of research, I got a list of invoices from the api. However, none of the invoices include the shopping cart information (the items they have ordered.). I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or help.

Config file --->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <!--<startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>-->
    <configSections>
      <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.SDKConfigHandler, PayPal" />
    </configSections>

    <!-- PayPal SDK settings -->
    <paypal>
      <settings>
        <add name="mode" value="live" />
        <add name="clientId" value=" client id" />
        <add name="clientSecret" value="client Secret" />
      </settings>
    </paypal>
</configuration>
```

C# Code --->

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using PayPal.Api;

namespace PaypalConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Authenticate with PayPal
            var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();
            var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();
            var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken); 
            var test = Invoice.GetAll(apiContext, pageSize: 10, totalCountRequired: true); 
        }
    }
}
```

Update:
Link to SDK--> https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK

Comment: You will get the items when you use [Invoices Get](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/v1/#invoices_get) for a single invoice. Repeat that for all invoices you are looking for

Comment: @SirRufo You are absolutely correct!!! If you post that as the answer, I will mark it correct. Thank you so much!